# PHP regex for validating currency

Tags: php, regex, validation

I need a regex to validate currency. Allowed values are:

```
1209
1889.0
578247.00
75646.50
But not 44565.12
```

The second number after comma must be 0. And available currency range is 0.1-9999999.9 .
Thanks for help.

Comment: So let me see if I've got this right. You want someone else to write your code for you? And where's the part where you research and learn so as to avoid running to SO for a regex every time you need one? SO !== Free Regex

Comment: @rdlowrey He don't need someone else to write his code he just need a pattern.That's all. `SO !== Free Regex` with this I agree ))

Comment: I have just started learning regex. I can understand what patterns mean but I can`t write my own patterns yet. And the best way of learning something is asking questions someone who nows the answers :)

Comment: @Rafael: actually, the best way to learn is finding online sandboxes, and tutorials/cheat cheats: 
http://www.functions-online.com/regular-expression.html 
http://www.regular-expressions.info/

http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php

Comment: @RafaelSedrakyan - The best way when learning things is to give it a go - you usually learn the most from making mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this pattern: `([1-9]\d{,6}|0)(\.\d0?)?`
with this pattern 1234.2 will be allowed.is it OK?
I edited the pattern, take a look.
First digit can't be 0 if there are other digits before the dot. So number must start with a non-zero digit and can have at most 6 digits after first and before dot or can  have only zero before dot ( this part`([1-9]\d{,6}|0)`).
`\d0?` means one digit and there may be a zero after it. `\.` is just a dot.

Comment: Yes. It is ok ). What about {,7}? Shouldn`t I use {1,7} instead of it?

Comment: 4ei spasum vor stex el hayi khandipem :)

Comment: Eli {,6}-i arajin tivy moracel es bajc ashxatuma vonc vor petqa :). Shnorhakalutjun ognutjan hamar. Facebookum karam avelacnem friendneris mej?

Comment: che, hima chishta.ete liner `[1-9]\d{1,6}|0` ed depqum skzbum minimum 2 tiv man kgar: mi hat es--> `[1-9]` mi hatel es--> `\d{1,6}` u asenq `1.10`-i hamar cher ashxati. {,6} nuynna inch {0,6}
facebook.com/fanofpinkfloyd

Comment: uxxaki es tutorialum (http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php) grvaca vor arajin tivy petqa misht grel. Es 0-i masin ei asum. Haskanum em vor 1 dnem avel nisher tujl kta. 4najac meka arandzin mijakajqy stugum em

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested a regex isn't the best way of dealing with numbers.

You could add additional simple range checks to the code below if needed and it'll be considerably faster than trying to do this with regexps

```
<?php

$a = array(
1209,
1889.0,
578247.00,
75646.50,
44565.12
);

foreach ($a as $b) {
    echo "$b - ";
    echo ($b*100 % 50) == 0 ? 'PASS' : 'FAIL';
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```